# Using Mailchimp API with Shopify

Tags: php, shopify, mailchimp

I am attempting to use the Mailchimp API to allow site visitors to subscribe to my newsletter. Currently, any signups with the default form action that Mailchimp provides sends an Opt-In email and opens a new email to say thanks for subscribing, which I want to avoid. Instead, if I use the API, I can set those options to false. The problem is that it doesn't look like Shopify allows PHP or Ruby in their shop code. I've been looking for weeks for a solution, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: You'd use JavaScript ajax to access a hidden PHP file which contains everything needed to communicate with the MailChimp API.  If Shopify doesn't even allow you to upload/run PHP files, then there is likely nothing else you can do.

Comment: No idea if this would do you any good:  http://kb.mailchimp.com/integrations/other-integrations/use-mailchimp360-for-shopify

Comment: Shopify does not allow you to run PHP files. It looks like they may allow Ruby, but I haven't had luck finding a good example. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a turnaround for this:

1.- Create a Wufoo form with one only field: email address.

2.- Paste this Wufoo form at your [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) store. We'd recommed pasting the JavaScript version. 
It can look like this

[image]

3.- On your notifications tab at your Wufoo form, choose to Send notifications to Another Aplication. On the dropdown, choose MailChimp click on Add integration and follow steps. You will be sending all email addresses to your desired MailChimp list.

[image]

Tiny problem is that placeholders on Wufoo forms, don't disappear on click, so the user needs to go inside the field and delete all the placeholder. (This might be a good point because robots can't do this, and you make sure the user is really involved in the process of typig his/her email address.)